# Discord.js How to make a Name Change History Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a code which shows the history of you name changes, like NotSoBot

[image]

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

These bots use their own database. Discord does not record these changes. You cannot do this only with discord.js. The only thing is that if your bot isn't very large, It will not be very efficient because your bot can't access every user that change username. And if your bot is offline or any username before your bot starting to record these changes cannot be tracked.

If you still want to do this, use a database and the discord.js event [userUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.3.2/class/Client?scrollTo=e-userUpdate) and record all usernames. Just note that this event is triggering even if the avatar of the user is changed or discriminator.

Comment: Nickname changes are stored in the audit log, which is something that a discord bot can have access to. Databasing, in some cases, may be faster, however, like you said, there are numerous things that can make that option not ideal. But to say `You cannot do this only with discord.js` is simply not true.

Comment: I think that when he said a bot that have past usernames, he isn’t saying a bot that says nickname but usernames. So not only limited to guilds. And if the guild have a lot of nickname logs, he can’t fetch everything in one request.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and yes, if the user is changing their actual discord username, the only way to log that is through databases and a ton of checks (which may end up being API spam if they want 100% accuracy [or close to it].) But he still can fetch the nickname logs in one request (as long as the user doesn't literally change their nickname every second) using the `.fecthAuditLogs` options.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use Audit Logs to fetch all name changes --  I recommend you do some [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs) research.

I will not provide you with the complete code you are looking for, but a stepping stone for you to figure it out on your own.

What you will want to do is fetch the audit logs, and specify the options based on given parameters that are implemented in your command. (i.e. the user who you want to search.)

A simple way of retrieving name changes:

```js
message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'MEMBER_UPDATE', user: 'DESIRED USER ID'}).then(async (audit) => {
        let log = audit.entries.first().changes
        console.log(log)
    })
```

OUTPUT:

```js
[ { key: 'nick', old: , new: } ]
```

`Key` as in the nickname is what you are looking for. `Old` is the old nickname. `New` is the new nickname.

This should point you in the right direction, as the rest is not too complex.